# R: How do I convert a dataframe of strings into POSIXt objects?

Tags: r, posixct

I have a dataframe of strings representing times, such as:

```
times <- structure(list(exp1 = c("17:19:04 \r", "17:28:53 \r", "17:38:44 \r"), 
                        exp2 = c("17:22:04 \r", "17:31:53 \r", "17:41:45 \r")), 
                        row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

If I run `strptime()` on a single element of my dataframe `times`, it converts it into a nice POSIXt object:

```
strptime(times[1,1], '%H:%M:%S')
```

> [1] "2020-02-19 17:19:04 GMT"

Great, so now I'd like to convert my whole dataframe `times` into this format.

I cannot seem to find the solution to do this smoothly.

A few of the things I have tried so far:

```
strptime(times, '%H:%M:%S') # generates NA
strftime(times, '%H:%M:%S') # Error: do not know how to convert 'x' to class “POSIXlt”
apply(times, 2, function(x) strftime(x, '%H:%M:%S')) # Error: character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

The closest I got to what I want is:

```
apply(times, 2, function(x) strptime(x, '%H:%M:%S'))
```

It generates a messy list. I can probably find a way to use it, but there must be a more staightforward way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `lapply`.

```
times[] <- lapply(times, strptime, '%H:%M:%S')
#                  exp1                exp2
# 1 2020-02-19 17:19:04 2020-02-19 17:22:04
# 2 2020-02-19 17:28:53 2020-02-19 17:31:53
# 3 2020-02-19 17:38:44 2020-02-19 17:41:45
```

Note: `apply` also works.

```
times[] <- apply(times, 2, function(x) strptime(x, '%H:%M:%S'))
```

The trick is to replace the columns (in contrast to overwriting the data frame with a list) with `[] <-`, which can be seen as abbreviated for `times[1:2] <- lapply(times[1:2], ·)` in this case.

Comment: Right, I think that's the same output as my `apply(times, 2, function(x) strptime(x, '%H:%M:%S'))`. I was hoping there'd be a way to get a dataframe of the same dimension as output though?

Comment: Yeah, just had the same idea you'd want a data frame:) See edit!

Comment: Notice that I've added some explanation.